# Kerberos authentication with Symfony2

Tags: symfony, kerberos

I am trying to authenticate users with kerberos in Symfony2 but I'm a little lost on the way.

When the user is authenticated,the Apache server returns the `$ _SERVER ['REMOTE_USER']` variable, giving me his username. I can recover this value :

```
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$user = $request->server->get('REMOTE_USER');
```

But how to tell Symfony to authenticate the user just with this value ? No password is required.

I hesitate between create a [custom authentication provider](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_authentication_provider.html) or create a [custom use provider](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_provider.html).

What is the best way to do this please ?

Comment: A custom User Provider doesn't seem right, as that interface has getPassword() and getSalt() methods.  Custom Authentication Provider seems right, and all you would do is vacuously return success (as authentication has occurred a priori).  Something like class KerberosTicket extends AbstractToken and class KerberosClientProvider implements AuthenticationProviderInterface

Comment: Ok thanks bishop, I will try this method.

Answer (score 5):

### Added a REMOTE_USER based listener to security firewalls

Several Apache security modules (auth_kerb, auth_cas, etc.) provide the username via an environment variable called REMOTE_USER. For that reason, Symfony 2.6 will include a new authentication listener based on this variable.

To use it in your application, simply define a firewall of the new remote_user type in your security configuration:

```
# app/config/security.yml
security:
    firewalls:
        secured_area:
            pattern: ^/
            remote_user:
                provider: your_user_provider
```

Source: http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-6-security-component-improvements